# How to repeat getting user's input and keep track of it?

Tags: python

I have a question about input loops and keeping track of it.

I need to make a program that will keep track of all the grades of a class. The thing is that the class size varies every semester, so there is no fixed number assigned to the number of students.

The program will stop taking input when a student enters a grade of -1.

```
while True:
    grade = int(input("Test: "))
    if grade < 0:
        break
```

How can I make it so that it keeps track of every single input?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comp with iter and get the user to enter -1 to end the loop:

```
grades = [int(grade) for grade in iter(lambda:input("Enter grade or -1 to exit: "), "-1")]
```

`iter` takes a sentinel that will break the loop when entered, so as soon as the user enters -1 the loop will end.

When taking input and casting you should really use a try/except to validate what the users inputs:

```
grades = []
while True:
    try:
        grade = int(input(""Enter grade or -1 to exit: ""))
    except ValueError:
        # user entered bad input 
        # so print message and ask again
        print("Not a valid grade")
        continue
    if grade == -1:
        break
    grades.append(grade) # input was valid and not -1 so append it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grades = [] # initialize an empty list
while True:
    grade = int(input("Test: "))
    if grade < 0:
        break
    else:
        grades.append(grade) # add valid values to the list
```

Comment: Thank you this really works. Do you know how to take each value and maybe add the values of get an average?

Comment: `sum(grades)/len(grades)`

Comment: you should better check if input is numeric or not. otherwise your program will crash. e.g. `int("abc")`

Comment: There are many things the program could check for at this point. This answer solves and explains the question at hand.

Comment: Great, @TigerhawkT3 I have another question if you do not mind. I have to translate the grade to a letter, for example between 90-100 is an A. Well, the problem is that I don't know how to pick each grade individually and then show next to it the letter that corresponds to it. any idea?

Comment: That's too much to answer in a comment. Try it yourself, do what research you can, and then - if you can't figure it out - post a new question.