# How to make an array to find an average score?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to make an average score that lists a student's average score with this:

```
name = input("Name: ")

first_score = int(input("First score: "))
second_score = int(input("Second score: "))
third_score = int(input("Third score: "))

avg_score = (first_score + second_score + third_score)/3

print("Hello, " + name + ". Your average score is: ")
print(avg_score)
```

But this is only for one person. How do I record n number of students that I want to input with an array?

Comment: you need to use for loop

Comment: "that I want to input with an array?" You need to clarify what your *exact* input would be, and what corresponding *exact* output you expect.

Comment: Use loop structure.

Comment: @deadshot thank you for the reference! I will study this.

Comment: @deadshot [Where did I use for loop?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/vzg5vyi1WMFWISezuEQjN7FAIzOvREchsyS1CMgqKAWy1dU1NTW5CoqAEhoQ5Zr//xtzGXKZADEXAA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - repeat input and keep track of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060156/python-repeat-input-and-keep-track-of-it)

Answer (score 0):

Example for the several students:

```py
students_count: int = 2


def input_student():
    name = input("Name: ")

    first_score = int(input("First score: "))
    second_score = int(input("Second score: "))
    third_score = int(input("Third score: "))

    avg_score = (first_score + second_score + third_score) / 3

    return name, avg_score


student_scores = [input_student() for _ in range(0, students_count)]

for name, avg_score in student_scores:
    print(f"Hello, {name}. Your average score is: {avg_score}")
```

For the several scores:

```py
students_count: int = 2


def input_student():
    name = input("Name: ")

    scores = []

    while s := input("Score: "):
        scores.append(int(s))

    avg_score = sum(scores) / len(scores)

    return name, avg_score


student_scores = [input_student() for _ in range(0, students_count)]

for name, avg_score in student_scores:
    print(f"Hello, {name}. Your average score is: {avg_score}")
```

Output for the first code snippet:

```py
Name: 213
First score: 2
Second score: 2
Third score: 3
Name: 123
First score: 2
Second score: 34
Third score: 2
Hello, 213. Your average score is: 2.3333333333333335
Hello, 123. Your average score is: 12.666666666666666
```

Comment: is there a way to keep the code for several students going? I tried it and it stopped after the first average score finished.

Comment: You can change `students_count` variable, and yes, `range(0, students_count)`, of course (from zero, not from the one).

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! I will study over this.